# Select an object by name with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My array, `var object`:
[image]

My return, `var data`:
[image]

I want to insert the value of `data` in the `object` that match.

**For example:**
Set the value of input that has name email(object[4]) as the data that has name email (data.email)

Comment: I am sorry sir. I have no idea what you are asking for. And I am really trying.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking and posting an image of code is not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [jQuery attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to find the specific element that might contain the name of your key and then find a matching element with that ID and then set its value:

```
// Iterate through your data keys
for (var key in data) {
    // Find an element that contains the key in its ID
    $('[id*="' + key + '"]').val(data[key]);
}
```

**Example**

```js
var data = {
  'first_name': 'Rion',
  'last_name': 'Williams'
};

for (var key in data) {
  $('[id*="' + key + '"]').val(data[key]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='x_first_name' />
<input id='x_last_name' />
```

Comment: Thanks! This is based on id, but help my to discover the solution.

Comment: Your current example has '#' characters for the input fields that you provided, which generally indicate that is the 'id' attribute for that element. If you need to target the name attribute specifically, then just change `id` to `name` in the selector.

Comment: Yeah! Thats what i did.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of a named input with the following selector.

```
$("input[name=nameGoesHere]").val();
```